# Creating ConfigurationManager with existing file on x86 platform while running NUnit project

Tags: .net, x86, nunit, configuration-files

Hi I am having a problem with NUnit and ConfigurationManager

I have several unti tests to test manipulation of a configuration file. in most of my tests I create a file and delete it at the end of the test.

However I have 2 tests where I create the file using new ConfigurationManager(path);
I then attempt to re-open the same file with the same path again using new ConfigurationManager(path);

I create an NUnit project and run it along with a few other nunit tests.

Recently we were forced to fix our platform to x86 (due to 3rd party components)

Prior to this change everything worked fine but now I constantly get an exception during the above mentioned tests and specifically on the line new ConfigurationManager(path);
The exception is IO.FileNotFoundException and refering to one of my application libraries.

Also to confuse me even more, the exception only occurs when I run the test via the project. It does not occur when I run the test using visual studios or when I add the dll directly to the nunit client (drag and drop)

Thanks in advance for any help

K

-EDIT:
I have added the exceptions and the config file xml for reference

> Hornbill.UnitTests.Configuration.ConfigurationManagerBasics.TestAppendGetDelete:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : An error occurred
>   creating the configuration section handler for hornbill.settings:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Hornbill.Application.Core,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (C:\Users\KieranJS\AppData\Local\TestConfigurationFile1.xml line 4)
>   ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Hornbill.Application.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="hornbill.settings" type="Hornbill.Configuration.Sources.Entities.SettingsSection, Hornbill.Application.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </configSections>
    <hornbill.settings>
        <forms>
            <form id="Hornbill.LoginModule">
                <item id="Test1">
                    <value>TestValue1</value>
                </item>
            </form>
        </forms>
    </hornbill.settings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem by changing the NUnit setting: Test Loader - Default Process Model to "Run tests in a separate process per Assembly"